# Run Android emulator with graphic accelaration

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run the android emulator with -gpu on (from the command line since I made changes to the platform), however the emulator won't start (I also get errors along the way).

Am I supposed to install some app on my Ubuntu in order for the emulator to be using graphics acceleration?

The errors I get are:

```
destroyOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
createOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
createOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
In the logcat, I get this:
E/FramebufferNativeWindow( 1305): couldn't open framebuffer HAL (I/O error)
E/        ( 1305): Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-gingerbread-emulator/ did you follow this guide from intel? (adding only -gpu on doesn't really increace perfomance)

Comment: This guide tells me to run kvm which is already running. I think the solution to this problem requires that I download an openGL driver for Ubuntu that matches with my current hardware (I haven't done that yet).